# NullPointerException - reading not empty file returns Null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm fairly new to programming and I wanted to learn how to read data from a file. I watched this video and tried to copy the idea for my own purpose.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RNYUKxAgmw

Whenever I try to run my main it says Error Line 22 - NullPointerException. I have a text file with numbers and I have checked if the names match. I simply do not understand why it says my file is empty.

```
package uge4;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {

    private Scanner x;
    public void openFile () {
        try {
            x = new Scanner (new File("gradeconverter.txt"));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert old grade ");
        int grade = input.nextInt();
        input.close();

    // line 22 
    while(x.hasNextInt()) {
        int a = x.nextInt();
        int b = x.nextInt();
        if ( a == grade) {
            System.out.println("Your new grade is: "+b);
        }
    }
}

public void closeFile() {
    x.close();
}
}
```

Comment: This is my .txt file
13 12
11 12
10 10
9 7
8 7
7 4
6 2
5 0
3 0
0 -3

Comment: I suspect what's actually happened is that your `x` variable is null. Was there a "File not found." prompt in the console when you ran it? Had you actually called `openFile()` before you called `readFile()`?

Comment: did you call `openFile` before `readFile`?

Comment: Usually "NullPointerExeption" means that something is not initialized, try to debug it

Comment: This is the order of my main. 
  ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
  r.openFile();
  r.readFile();
  r.closeFile();

Comment: Ah - in that case your problem is that you're trying to use `x` before you've initialised it. You need to call `openFile()` to initialise `x` otherwise you can't use it.

Comment: This is my first time using debug so not sure if I got it right but after i ran it I got the message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at uge4.ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:22)
 at uge4.GradeConverter.main(GradeConverter.java:8)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [util.c:840]

Answer (score 2):

After first `int a = x.nextInt()` calls another `int b = x.nextInt();`, it may happend that `x` Scanner has no more data to return. You need to check `x.hasNextInt()` before each call of `x.nextInt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it is because you havnt specified the path of your file

if you are uding a file from your pc/latop's harddisk please give the complete path

```
x = new Scanner (new File("C://newfolder//gradeconverter.txt"));// just an example, add the actual path of you files location
```

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot for all the help every1 :) now.. is there a way to set default pathing? So if i save the file under my workspace i would not have to add the path each time

Comment: @Tacolips you can take an global variable where you add the path of your   external directory(or workspace) and the n give that variable each and every place

Answer (score 0):

Can u simply use the java 8 "way"

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_PATH)).forEach(System.out::print);
```

PS: You have forget to open the `Scanner` -> x